# How to update a variable updated in c++ in qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I know how to update qml variables using `Q_PROPERTY`.

```
class _data: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    _data();
    ~_data();

    Q_PROPERTY(int testflag READ getTestFlag WRITE setTestFlag NOTIFY testFlagChanged);
    int m_testFlag;
    auto getTestFlag() -> int {return m_testFlag;}
    auto setTestFlag(int data) -> void {this->m_testFlag = data; emit testFlagChanged();}
signals:
    void testFlagChanged();
}
```

When updating the `m_testFlag` variable in c++ using the code above, the `testFlagChanged()` signal must be called forcibly to update the value in qml.

```
_data* mydata;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    mydata = new _data;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mydata", data);
    view.show();
    app.installEventFilter(new myEventFilter(&view)); // Added an event filter to operate the Update() function when a keyboard event is received. I checked that it works, so I omitted the separate code.
    return app.exec();
}

void update() {
    mydata->m_testFlag = 10;
    mydata->testFlagChanged();
}
```

Isn't there a way to update the qml variable in a more elegant way other than forcibly calling the `testFlagChanged()` signal?

I've been looking for something like signal bind, but I haven't been able to find any examples I can use. I need help.

> Edit

I posted a question with test code, but I didn't expect it to receive so much criticism.
I will fix it in the function update() function and write more details about my question. So calm down and take a look at the code.

I am trying to update m_testFlag variable in c++ by declaring it as public in a class called data.
At this time, I want the changed() signal to be generated automatically when the variable value is changed, rather than forcibly generated by the developer. Is there any better way?

Comment: [OT]: `setTestFlag` should be `if (m_testFlag == data;) {m_testFlag = data; emit testFlagChanged();}` to not emit signal when nothing change.

Comment: With above code, you only have to write one `emit testFlagChanged()`, and use the setter to modify the variable. Not sure the wanted alternative you want.

Comment: @hyde I understand now. There are too many errors in the question that makes it not possible to answer.

Comment: @StephenQuan Yeah, Stack Overflow tries to maintain a level of quality, and even if it'd be possible to guess what some unclear question means and provide an answer to that assumed real question, that should be avoided. Or, if there is no real ambiguity, edit the question before answering. But I think this question is beyond guessing what it means, and the OP should do the editing to get it right. Disclaimer: I'm not a mod or anything, so this is just a user's opinion, YMMV.

Comment: @hyde I've improved the code a bit more. Please check once more.

Comment: @Jarod42 typo in your example is `==` should be `!=`.

Comment: Offtopic2: class name `_data` is invalid since global scope symbols starting with underscore are reserved for a compiler.

Comment: @MarekR: indeed, and extra `;` too. A little late to fix.

Comment: [OT]: `setTestFlag` should be `if (m_testFlag != data) {m_testFlag = data; emit testFlagChanged();}` to not emit signal when nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Isn't there a way to update the qml variable in a more elegant way other than forcibly calling the testFlagChanged() signal?"* -- A "more elegant way" can be subjective, but I think all you need to do is instead of this:

```
    mydata->m_testFlag = 10;
    mydata->testFlagChanged();
```

call this:

```
    mydata->setTextFlag(10);
```

Also, don't make m_testFlag public unless you have a really good reason to. It should be private. That's the whole purpose of having getter/setter functions, so outside objects don't need to know the internals of the class.